# How to test websites in IE 6 when running Windows 7?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there a way to install Internet Explorer 6 in Windows 7? I need to test the layout of a website. Using a website which takes screenshots is a bit awkward, as often you are making changes and testing the effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

Install [Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) (free) or Virtualbox and use the [IE VPC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

You can also try the [Xenocode Browser Sandboxes](http://www.xenocode.com/browsers/), but I've run into a couple situations where they're not entirely compatible.

Comment: You can also use a service like browsershots if the site is hosted somewhere on the internet and you just want to see what a page looks like without interaction. The VPC way is definitely the best solution though.

Comment: Does anyone know if Win7's XP mode will work to run IE6? That might be a better option. http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Comment: Just for reference: Yes, XP mode wil work - it comes with IE6, not IE7. This lets you keep it around for testing without the image expiring, like the IE VPC images are supposed to do. (Although the one I downloaded back when they introducd it never actually did expire, even though it claimed it would.)

Comment: This answer is outdated. Try using Windows Virtual PC: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b6d5c18-1441-47ea-8309-2545b08e11dd###

Answer (score 3):

I think [IE6 and IE7 Running on a Single Machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/11/30/ie6-and-ie7-running-on-a-single-machine.aspx) is the recommended way.

Comment: I was going to delete this because John Sheehan answered a few seconds earlier then me, but now I have to keep this: My first answer with a negative score! \o/

Comment: Awwwww--, is't not negative any more. ;_;

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Expression Web Superpreview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e6cc9b3e-7eab-4525-8322-14d7e267eb2c&displaylang=en) that can be used for comparing websites in different versions of IE side by side.  I believe the standalone free version is for IE comparisons only, but if you have a full version of Expression Web you can compare IE and FireFox renderings side by side.

Comment: Hell yes. This is the most fantastic feature. I have NO IDEA why Dreamweaver doesn't have this... BrowserLab sucks.

Comment: The link in this post is dead, but you can install SuperPreview through the Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 2):

The IETester is my favorite: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

> IETester is a free WebBrowser that
>   allows you to have the rendering and
>   javascript engines of IE8, IE7 IE 6
>   and IE5.5 on Windows 7, Vista and XP,
>   as well as the installed IE in the
>   same process.

Comment: In my experience for moderate/complex js/css it is not very reliable.

Comment: agreed, the Utilu IE bundle worked better for me than IETester

Answer (score 0):

http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ is good for instantly getting screenshots of your site in IE. Of course, it only returns images but it's good for testing a layout!